# Python eval printing an extra \n for a z3 expression

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval, z3, z3py

I have narrowed down my problem in the following code. I am trying to convert a string into equivalent z3 expression. The problem is that when the variable name is big, the 'eval' puts extra \n in between the expression but if I use a smaller variable name the extra \n is not there. I need to have a bigger variable name because that is not under my control. Please suggest how can I make the code working correctly with bigger variable names

EXTRA \n PRODUCING CODE

```
from z3 import BitVec, Solver #@UnresolvedImport

z3sig_dict = {}
z3sig_dict['v__DOT__process_1_reg3'] = {"z3name":BitVec('v__DOT__process_1_reg3', 32), "bits":32}
z3sig_dict['v__DOT__process_1_reg3_1'] = {"z3name":BitVec('v__DOT__process_1_reg3_1', 32), "bits":32}
string = "(z3sig_dict['v__DOT__process_1_reg3']['z3name'] == (8 + (z3sig_dict['v__DOT__process_1_reg3_1']['z3name'] % 0x20000000)))"
s = Solver()
print(string)
clause = eval(string)
print(str(clause))
s.add(clause)
```

The output of this code is

```
(z3sig_dict['v__DOT__process_1_reg3']['z3name'] == (8 + (z3sig_dict['v__DOT__process_1_reg3_1']['z3name'] % 0x20000000)))
v__DOT__process_1_reg3 ==
8 + v__DOT__process_1_reg3_1%536870912
```

CORRECTLY WORKING CODE

```
from z3 import BitVec, Solver #@UnresolvedImport

z3sig_dict = {}
z3sig_dict['reg3'] = {"z3name":BitVec('reg3', 32), "bits":32}
z3sig_dict['reg3_1'] = {"z3name":BitVec('reg3_1', 32), "bits":32}
string = "(z3sig_dict['reg3']['z3name'] == (8 + (z3sig_dict['reg3_1']['z3name'] % 0x20000000)))"
s = Solver()
print(string)
clause = eval(string)
print(str(clause))
s.add(clause)
```

The output of this code is

```
(z3sig_dict['reg3']['z3name'] == (8 + (z3sig_dict['reg3_1']['z3name'] % 0x20000000)))
reg3 == 8 + reg3_1%536870912
```

SOME OBSERVATIONS

If I reduce the  % 0x20000000 to % 0x2000, then also the code works correctly, but incorrectly if I add one more zero i.e 0x20000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 adds the \n because it thinks the output is too wide for the shell to print. By default, it assumes that only 80 characters fit into one line, but it's easy to tell Z3 to use more space:

```
from z3 import *

set_param(max_lines=1, max_width=1000000)
print(str(clause))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Could you suggest which modules exactly should I import from z3. I don't want to crowd the namespace by importing everything from z3 using *

Comment: set_param lives in the outermost scope, so you can do 'from z3 import set_param'

Comment: I get an error when I try to import it. The exact line I used is  
''   from z3 import BitVec, Solver, unsat, sat, Not, ULT, ULE, UGT, UGE, Or, And, ZeroExt, set_param #@UnresolvedImport    ''
''    ImportError: cannot import name set_param''

Comment: All of those work fine for me using python 2.7.x or python 3.4.x. Which versions of all the tools involved are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.5 and z3 4.3.0. I installed z3 around 2 years ago. I am running it on windows 7 using PyCharm IDE. In the IDE, I have added the z3 source files in the source folders list and all methods of z3 works fine except the 'set_param'

Comment: Before going any further, please update Z3 to 4.3.2. There were quite a lot of bugfixes since your version and the last one, many of them for the Python API.

Comment: Updated my z3 and tried your suggestions. Worked fine. Thanks